# ARKit Demo Crashing on iPhone 6/iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, ios11, arkit

I'm working with [ARKit Feature](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/) , with recent major iOS release, but I'm getting a crash with error `failed assertion`

> MTLRenderPassDescriptor: MTLStoreActionMultisampleResolve store action for the depth attachment is not supported by device

I already have iOS11 beta, installed in my iPhone device.

Comment: I believe ARKit supports only devices with Apple's A9 Processors(newer devices like 6s and above).

Answer (score 2):

As all answers above this is a `hardware constraint` to `A9` chips. Anyway it is a good practice to addAdding `ARKit` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` on `Info.plist` will give you a better feedback running apps that primary function is `ARKit` based.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to run ARKit your device should be able to support it. Not only using the latest iOS will help. As apple mention in the Keynote WWDC 2017 they support A9 chips and Above which means iPhone 6s and Above will be able to run and test ARKit.